# now() not working on InfoPath form (2013)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

Has anyone encountered an issue where the now() not working on the DateTime field in InfoPath on SP2013?  I copied it from another form that is working fine.  I compared the two and it appears to be the same.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen to only this list form? What if you create a new Date and Time field in this list and then insert the now() function again?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are following the below:

Select the textbox or field where you want to display the **now()** function -> Double click on that field -> click on the **Fx** link -> Click on the Insert function -> select **Date Time** from Categories -> select **now()**

[image: Infopath DateTime Issue]

It should work now. I have just tested it is working.

Output:
[image: Infopath DateTime Issue2]

**Update**

1. If **now()** does not, go to the textbox settings, change the **postback** settings to **always**  and check the checkbox for always refresh data.
2. If still does not work, add rule on form load then set the **now()** function value.

Comment: I’ve done this before and it’s not working. Not sure if there is anything that is preventing from displaying

Comment: Hi - check the updated answer, it might be helpful.

Comment: I don’t see the Post Back setting and adding the rule is not adding it.  So I’ll have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

One more setting to check:

Check if you have any format for the column data by right clicking on the control > Date Picker/Text Box Properties > **Format** under Data tab.

The format is set to **None** by default.

[image]

In addition, the *Postback settings* is under the Browser forms tab. Switch it to **Always** and see if it helps.

[image]